# PHP Default time at 23:59:59

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am running a sweepstakes page on my wordpress site. I already have the logic setup when create a sweepstakes post that the sweepstakes page already pulls in post based on custom fields for "start_date" and "end_date". The issue I am having is if a sweepstakes is set to start on 03/01/2014 and end on 03/19/2014 once the time hits midnight (12:00) the post is removed when it needs to continue throughout the 19th. Stated below is the query code I am using. And it works for posts with custom fields of start date and end date. I just almost need a default for the post to be removed in this case 03/19/2014 at time 23:59:59. I need a default time for 23:59:59. Is there a global change that will make post remove on the date specified just at 23:59:59? I hope this explains it.

```
 <?php // The Query     

    $startdate = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
    $enddate = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'sweepstakes_startdate',
                'value' => $startdate,
                'compare' => '<='

                ),
            array(
                'key' => 'sweepstakes_enddate',
                'value' => $enddate,
                'compare' => '>='

         )
       )
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: What datatypes are your columns `sweepstakes_startdate` and `sweepstakes_enddate`? `DATE`, `DATETIME`?

Comment: meta_key is sweeptstakes_startdate and sweepstakes_enddate and meta_value is the dates and time I specify. It all works just as expect if a time is specified, but if just a date is specified it ends as soon a date hits that date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no real shorthand for specifying that, aside from specifying the literal `'23:59:59'`.

Seems like the quickest patch is just some PHP logic to reset `$enddate` before it's sent to your query.

If the time component of `$enddate` is midnight, then add one day and subtract one second to the value sent to the query.

This does change the specification a bit; it means that specifying an enddate value of `'2014-03-19 00:00:00'` is equivalent to specifying and enddate value of `'2014-03-19 23:59:59'`, which basically means that it's not possible to specify a sweepstakes ending exactly midnight.  But you could end a sweepstakes at time `00:00:01`.

---

In MySQL, we'd typically specify the "end" of a period (like you describe) as midnight of the following day (rather than '23:59:59' of the preceding day), and use a "less than" comparison rather than a "less than or equal to" comparison.

For example:

```
WHERE mydatetimecol >= '2014-03-19'
  AND mydatetimecol <  '2014-03-20'
```

rather than

```
WHERE mydatetimecol >= '2014-03-19'
  AND mydatetimecol <= '2014-03-19 23:59:59'
```

MySQL does have some handy INTERVAL operations on DATETIME values...

```
WHERE mydatetimecol >= '2014-03-19'
  AND mydatetimecol <  '2014-03-19' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If I absolutely had to "back up" one second, I'd use an interval operation, for example:

```
WHERE mydatetimecol >= '2014-03-19'
  AND mydatetimecol <= '2014-03-19' + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL -1 SECOND
```

---

Note that some temporal values can actually have milliseconds precision, such as '23:59:59.997' where you could potentially leave a gap between the end of one period and the beginning of another, if you used '23:59:59'.

This isn't really a problem with temporal datatypes stored in MySQL (but other RDMBS such as SQL Server can store fractional seconds). And it's probably not a problem for your particular application (but in the more general case, we typically want for rows to fall into a particular bucket, and not fall between the cracks between the buckets.)

And, I'd be leery of adding 86,399 seconds to a date value, depending on whether the timezone is daylight savings time or not, there's some days that are 23 hours or 25 hours.

Comment: So how would you recommend that based on the current code I have? Just remove the "=" on the comparison?

Comment: @Anthony, that's what I would do. And I would have the users specify the date and time the sweepstakes is to "end"; if they want the sweepstakes to run through all day Sunday and end at Midnight, then specify "Monday" as the end date. (But, there will be some users that will be confused by that. When they say they want a sweepstakes to run until "Sunday", they won't expect it to end on "Saturday" night at 12:01AM Sunday morning.)

Answer (score 2):

```
$start_scheduled_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0,0,0)); 

$end_scheduled_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(23,59,59));
```

**output:**

> 2015-12-30 15:15:00
>
> 2015-12-31 00:00:00
>
> 2015-12-31 23:59:59